# Im using PIP to install splunklib in python but it fails

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to install splunklib but when i used pip to install it i get this error message: "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement splunklib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for splunklib"

My python version is 3.6.0 on a Win7
does anyone know whats causing it and workaround to fix this error>

Comment: Try with `python3 -m pip install splunklib`.

Comment: i tried your suggestion i got the same error msg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
pip install splunklib==1.0.0

Or:
python -m pip install splunklib==1.0.0

This forces pip to use the specified version. Version 1.0.0 is the most recent version found on pypi.org

Edit:  Since that didn’t work, try ‘pip install —upgrade pip’ to make sure your pip installation is up to date. Make sure to use double dashes before the word upgrade. If that doesn’t fix the issue, then this document may be of help.
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: I tried that 2 cmds but still got the same error message.

Comment: Is this a standalone python installation, or part of something like Visual Studio or FreeCAD?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install with "pip install splunklib". Since you are getting error, please post more error information along wiht Screenshots

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install splunklib
```

Solved the problem for me.